# Load an image from a dynamically or periodically updated path

Tags: javascript, apache, jenkins, debian

In my page i have this path for display an image.

***Example:***

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logo.png"/>
```

My image is not display, because on my `Apache` the path is:

```
/var/www/html/apps/stc-1.0-r-20170516195017/img/logo.png
```

The particularity off my path is my app is rebuild every day so this argument `stc-1.0-r-20170516195017 is dynamic`

My question is how can i do in javascript to get my path `/apps/static-[DYNAMIC_VALUE]/` ?

Hint: My root directory is : `/var/www/html/`

***My page:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logo.png" />
  <title>Erreur 404</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/theme.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="site">
      <div class="header" id="header-container">
        <header>
          <div id="header">
            <div class="inside">
              <div class="fl"><a class="header-link" title="Retour à l&#x27;accueil de Google" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="banner">
            <div role="banner" class="inside">
              <div class="fl menu-main-conteneur ">
                <nav id="menu-main" aria-label="Menu principal" data-title="Menu" class="menuHaut"></nav>
              </div>
              <div class="fl w10 mls">
                <a class="sub-header-link" href="/accueil" title="Retour vers la page d&#x27;accueil " id="img-logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Application" /></a>
              </div>
              <div class="fl mls">
                <a class="sub-header-link" href="/apps/accueil" title="  Retour vers la page d&#x27;accueil ">
                  <h1 id="app-title">Application </h1>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
      <main id="page" role="main">
        <span></span>
        <div id="nfe-page">
          <div id="nf-img"></div>
          <h2 class="nfe-title">Oops! Nous ne trouvons pas ce que vous cherchez!</h2><a href="/apps/accueil" class="button nfe-button">Retour à la page d&#x27;accueil</a>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer id="ft" class="footer-container" role="contentinfo">
        <div id="footer" class="footer-content inside">
          <div class="fl mll">
            <ul class="footer-links">
              <li><a href="/apps/planAppli" title="Plan de l&#x27;application l&#x27; Application ">Plan de l&#x27;application</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/apps/politiqueAccessibilite" title="Politique d&#x27;accessibilité de l&#x27; Application ">Accessibilité</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/apps/contact" title="Contact de l&#x27; Application ">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="fr mrl">
            <p>Application </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What decides what the dynamic value is?

Comment: what is the root directory ?

Comment: Configure the web server to serve the latest version of the image under the URL `/img/logo.png`, don't make the client-side guess.

Comment: Can't you keep your `img` directory and the files in under your app directory?

Comment: @Liam is decide when you build the app on jenkins

Comment: @MTroy `/var/www/html/`

Comment: @deceze you do this on your `apache.conf`

Comment: can you put a little bit of conf related to the generated path ?

Answer (score 0):

## The better way

Is to apply some change under your configs files.
but since i don't have not enough explaination about them...

## Alternative

In your case, you can bypass the dynamic behavior 
by getting recursively the excepted file using the dynamic pattern:

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator
(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($you_root_dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
);

foreach ($iter as $path => $fileinfo)
{
    if($fileinfo->isDir() && preg_match("/^stc-.*[\d]+$/i", $fileinfo->getFilename()))
    {
        $logo = $path."/img/logo.png";
        if(file_exists($path."/img/logo.png"))
        {
            header("Content-Type:image/png");
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($logo));
            readfile($logo);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if at creation, the static dir is preserved,
you should take the newest directory, by ignore the old stagged dirs.

```
// sort and get the newest dir
$dirs = [];
array_walk(scandir($path, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING),
function($d, $k) use(&$path, &$dirs)
{
    if(is_dir($path.$d) && !preg_match("/^\.+$/", $d))
        $dirs[filemtime($path.$d)] = $d;
});
ksort($dirs);

// check and show the img
$logo = array_pop($dirs)."/img/logo.png";
if(file_exists($logo))
{
    header("Content-Type:image/png");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($logo));
    readfile($logo);
}
```

You have to put the wanted code inside a new file called logo.php

and callable from your web root like :

```
<img src="logo.php">
```